# Debug React.js source code, not the react's DOM?

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in the actual React.js code, and to debug this code.

E.g.:

```js
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>; // Here goes breakpoint
  }
});

React.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

I mean debugging the actual React code rather then the compiled javascript code. Is there any solution (a plugin for a browser, any IDE supporting this)?

I know that when they talk about debugging react they mean the ability to see the React's shadow DOM. The question is about debugging the actual script code.

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe try [React developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)?

Comment: you can type `debugger` in your JS code and if your developer console is open when you view the site it'll let you step through the code.

Comment: That's what I tried. They show the React's DOM. But the code is Javascript. This means I write code in react-script, and debug javascript. Is there any solution? Maybe IDE plugins?

Comment: Adding breakpoint after return doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: This is an example code. The point is adding a breakpoint (anywhere)

Comment: Not a great answer, but if you're a typescripter like myself, then breakpoints work great.  Here's a nice github I found that has example TS code which breakpoints work out of the box:  https://github.com/Lemoncode/react-typescript-samples

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to add **debugger** directly inside .jsx file? It works for me every single time

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Chrome debugger show the original source (jsx), not the compiled javascript.